# How do I make vim open a particular line using a column format instead of plus?

Tags: vim

Generally if you want to open a file at a particular line number in vim, say line 36 you would do:

```
 vi +36 foo.c
```

Is there any way to change this default format in my `vimrc` file todo this in the following way:

```
 vi foo.c:36
```

The reason is that output from grep etc return line number in the latter format. 
I solved this problem using python. But looking for a better solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os

a=sys.argv[1].split(':')
order = r"/usr/bin/vim +" +  a[1]  +" " +  a[0]
print order
os.system(order)
```

another simple solution based on @phd comment is

```
cat ~/bin/dvim
vim `echo $1 | sed 's/:/ +/'`
```

But both solutions require me to create a new command.

Comment: To open Vim on the first line containing the word `abc`  you can do:  `vim -c "/abc" inputfile`

Answer (score 4):

A generic solution would be to use Vim's `-q` option together with process substitution to load grep's output in the quickfix list. Something like this if you properly planned ahead:

```
$ vim -q <(grep -nH foo *)
```

or this if you didn't:

```
$ vim -q <(!!)
```

Or you could simply ask Vim to grep for you if the end goal is to edit a file anyway:

```
$ vim +gr\ foo\ *
```

Or you could install [this little plugin](https://github.com/bogado/file-line).

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [file-line](https://github.com/bogado/file-line) plugin. It defines `:autocmd`s that take the appended line number, extract it, open the original file, and jump to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Nop, but you can parse/edit `grep` output and feed it to `vim`:

```
vim `grep -l | sed 's/:/ +/'`
```

Comment: didn't work. Besides, I often do `grep -in string1 *.c | grep string2` to reduce the number of hits. This often results in `foo.c:36`

Comment: `echo foo.c:36 | sed 's/:/ +/'` => `foo.c +36`. This is perfect command line to pass to vim.

Comment: I usually direct the output of grep to a file and open it with vim and use `gF` command to go there

Comment: Me too. Also with other tools, like `flake8`.